# Why does one jsfiddle work and the other does not, even though they have the exact same code?

Tags: html, jquery, css, imagemap, imagemapster

I'm trying to create a map in which each of its subsections highlight on hover. The best method I was told after researching was to use imagemapster which apparently functions, hence the first functional link... but in the second with the **exact same code** it doesn't. Am I missing something? If anyone knows it would be helpful

[This one works](http://jsfiddle.net/KSaunders123/j5zpnftq/6/)

[And this one doesn't](https://jsfiddle.net/KSaunders123/bx92f75w/1/)

I'm using imagemapster. **What I want is this**
....
[gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/307a7.gif)

```
var image = $('#vegetables');



image.mapster({
     fillColor: "0000"
 });
```

EDIT: the positioning of the image is bad. I apologize, it's just needed to scroll down a bit and to the right a bit.

Comment: Both jsfiddle are using jQuery but only the second one is importing it

Comment: @Axnyff I've just imported it, it's still not working though

Comment: Looks like you imported the jQuery version of imageMapster. You still need the actual jQuery library. See https://code.jquery.com/

Comment: I have imported it.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the menu immediately above the JS code.

One includes jQuery (an admittedly ancient version with security problems) and one doesn't.

The JS depends on jQuery so throws an error (open the developer tools, look at the console, **read the error messages**!) when it isn't available.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I've just imported the jquery (links are updated) however it's still not working

Comment: I have Included Jquery 1000 times.

Comment: Also, the imagemapster is somehow not importing either even though it says it is